# Did Kierkegaard believe that we should live seeking meaning and not happiness?

Tags: existentialism, meaning-of-life, happiness, kierkegaard

Before I pose my question I want to say two things:

1. I have no formal training in Philosophy
2. I searched for similar questions but found none, please excuse me if this is a duplicate

I saw a YouTube video (it's in Portuguese, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czfbY18UPqU) in which the youtuber states that one of Kierkegaard's ideas was that we should not seek happiness, we should seek meaning. His reasoning would be, in simple terms: "If we seek happiness, we will always regret our decision, we will look back and think 'I should have chosen differently', but if we seek meaning, even if we are not happy with our decision, we will have made the right choice, i.e., the choice that aligns with our principles". Is this a correct (even if oversimplified) assessment of some of Kierkegaard's philosophy?

Comment: Yes is the answer to your question